# Melt issues resulting in incorrect plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, melt

[image]Trying to plot multiple curves on one graph using ggplot2.  The x-axis will be wavelength, the y-axis will show intensity.

Data Table (called ‘Set’) is shown below (col2 refers to column 2 etc.), wavelength goes from 3600 to 8000 wavenumbers.  Each of col1, 2, 3 all have different values, leading to different curves. The columns provide values in intensity.

Wavelength  col1    col2    col3

The melt syntax can be found below, at melted.

```
    df<-data.table(Set)
    melted <- melt(df, id.vars = NULL, measure.vars=colnames(df), 
variable.name = "wavelength", value.name = "value")
```

```
wavelength  value
```

1:  Wavelength  3600.809

2:  Wavelength  3601.637

etc

To plot,

```
    ggplot(
      plot_input[wavelength %in% c("col1", "col2", "col3”)],
      aes(y=value, x=wavelength)) + 
      geom_line() + 
      theme_classic()
```

Issues –

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dg7t.png) ggplot output [per image] results in three vertical lines, am trying to plot three distinct curves for each of col1, col2, col3

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dg7t.png) ggplot – looking for wavenumbers on the x-axis, not col_num

[image: badly constructed plot]

I am probably missing something very simple.  Could someone explain what I am doing incorrectly?

Thank you.

[additional image added, apols for poor quality]. Shown are 5 spectra, in colours.  The data is contained in the columns - y values]

Comment: can you add outputs of `dput(head(Set,100))` command to let us discuss about your data ?

Comment: > dput((head(Set, 100)))
structure(list(X1 = "col1", X2 = "col2", X3 = "col3"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")

Comment: I updated my answer as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

The main question is that what x axis in the plot represents ?

Now I think it's what you desire to see

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1453)

Set <- data.frame(col1=sample(6000:7000,size = 20,replace = T),
                 col2=sample(6000:7000,size = 20,replace = T),
                 col3=sample(6000:7000,size = 20,replace = T))

df <- data.table(Set)

melted <- melt(df, id.vars = NULL, measure.vars=colnames(df), 
variable.name = "wavelength", value.name = "value")

melted %>%
ggplot(aes(x=value,color=wavelength))+
geom_density()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, the example I gave was to illustrate the point.  I have about 100 columns of data I want to plot (to illustrate a particular feature).  The y data is the (signal) intensity of data in various columns, per column number

Comment: @Screamh ok I updated this, I meant what x axis should represent.

Comment: Samet, x axis is the inverse of wavelength, going from about 3600 to 8000 wavenumbers.

Comment: @Screamh okay, what about y axis ?

Comment: The y data is the (signal) intensity of data in various columns, per column number

Comment: @Screamh I edited in that way, x axis represents "wavenumbers", y axis represents "intensity" and each waveline has unique curve..

Comment: @Screamh welcome, you can approve my answer if it fixed your issue.